# Where can i download Google Sketchup 7?

Tags: windows-7, download

Where can I download Google Sketchup 7, but not the Pro version?

Answer (score 3):

For version 7 you could try this link from FileHippo:
[Google SketchUp 7.0.10247](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_sketchup/download/70c4416814873382a14e56d143c99c20/)

There are also many other versions available at [Google SketchUp's FileHippo page](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_sketchup/).

Answer (score 1):

For reference, Trimble has acquired SketchUp and both versions can be downloaded from the official [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/download/index.html) site.